# как найти совпадающие значения в map?

Tags: c++, map

не могли бы вы подсказать, как можно пройтись по контейнеру map, найти повторяющиеся значения и вывести их вместе с ключами, то есть [**значение: ключи в которых значение совпало**].

я создал мап, в котором тип ключа - char (то есть повторяющиеся значения исходника), тип значения - vector  (здесь хранятся ключи, которые совпали)

в Итоге у меня ничего не работает: не сортирует, и не выводит, не знаю, что делать

не могли бы вы подсказать как можно это сделать?
спасибо заранее

мой код

М-исходный мап/с - содержащий результаты

```
for (map <int, char>::iterator it = M.begin(); it != M.end(); it++)
{
    c[it->second].push_back(it->first);
}

for (map <char, vector<int>>::iterator it = c[it->second].begin(); it != c[it->second].end(); it++)
{
    if (it->second.size() <= 1)continue;

    cout << "значение=" << it->first << ", " << " ключи:"<<it->second.size();
    for (map <char, vector<int>>::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << it->second << ",  ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
```

Comment: Вас не задачка с синонимами интересует? :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1119910/195342

Comment: @Harry, извините, нет.
тот ответ я уже читал, но это не то, к сожалению(((((

Comment: приведите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: В общем случае - только обход всего контейнера подряд. Вам бы поменять структуру, какую-то посложнее, с двумя индексами - по ключам и по значениям. Готовой подсказать не могу, а писать свою - не так уж просто, в общем-то...

Comment: @Harry, как мне можно вывести содержимое вектора, который находится в мапе с без авто для вывода последнего?
просто я другого варианта не вижу, помимо авто, а нам в задачах его использовать нельзя(

извиняюсь за то, что вопрос не по теме немного

Comment: @Harry, там я старался обратиться к этому внутреннему вектору для вывода, но он ругается и не выводится ничего

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заполняется `c` правильно, а вот обход и вывод неправильный

```
for (map<char, vector<int>>::iterator it_map = c.begin(); it_map != c.end(); it_map++) {   
    vector<int> &keys = it_map->second;
    if (keys.size() <= 1) continue;

    cout << "значение=" << it_map->first << ", " << " ключи: ";
    for (vector<int>::iterator it_vec = keys.begin(); it_vec != keys.end(); it_vec++) {
        cout << it_vec << ",  ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

или гораздо проще через [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

```
for (pair<char, vector<int>>& p: c) {   
    vector<int> &keys = p->second;
    if (keys.size() <= 1) continue;

    cout << "значение=" << p->first << ", " << " ключи: ";
    for (int x: keys) {
        cout << x << ",  ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: вы очень выручили, благодарю очень!